# unexpected result using typer

Tags: types, erlang

I decided to add type definition in some of my code, and I ran Typer to get a starting point (erlang 15b02, typer 0.9.4).

I picked some results to check if every thing is fine and found this result that I don't understand:

```
par(true, o) -> "(";
par(true, f) -> ")";
par(_, _) -> "".
```

which produce the spec:

```
-spec par(boolean(),'f' | 'o') -> [40 | 41].
```

I can understand the input parameters because this function is not exported, and my code only call the function with a boolean expression as first parameter, and the atoms o or f as second one (for example `par(4 > P, o)` ).

**But why the return list does not include the empty list?** I was expecting something like `[40 | 41 | []]` or `[40 | 41 | ""]`

this code is used for printing math expressions and avoid parenthesis when the priority or operator is sufficient; for example print

`3 + 4 + 5 * (6 + 7) - sin( x + 7)`  rather than

`3 + ( 4 + (( 5 * ( 6 + 7 )) - sin(( x + 7))))`.

I am sure that the code is called with false as first parameter as shown by the result of test coverage:

```
    15..|  par(true, o) -> "(";
    15..|  par(true, f) -> ")";
   308..|  par(_, _) -> "".
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an [Erlang type specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html), `[X]` means "a list of zero or more elements of type `X`".  In your case, `X` is `40 | 41`, so `"("`, `")"`, `"()()"` and `""` all match this type.  There is no way to express a list of exactly one element as a type spec.

A list with at least one element could be specified as `[X,...]`.  The fact that typer says `[40 | 41]` instead of `[40 | 41,...]` implies that it knows that the function can return an empty list.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember the meaning of ... although it is used in other results.